# What does "goes" mean in "zinc paint that goes on those stainless steel cables"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> IF you've ever been to San Francisco, you know that the Golden gate bridge is red.
>   And it's red because of the zinc paint that **goes** on those stainless steel cables.

Please tell me: What does "goes" means in this sentence?

Comment: I believe this is an extended sense 11 [here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/go): "if something goes somewhere, that is its usual position", or sense 32.3 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go#Verb): "To belong (somewhere).".

Comment: I think wiki 32.3 answer the question.
I want to thank you, not only because you give me the answer, but also you taught me use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase:

> . . . it's red because of the zinc paint that **has been applied to** those stainless steel cables.

In short, paint *goes on* something. In this particular case, it *goes on* the bridge's stainless steel cables.

Merriam-Webster's [seventeenth sense](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go) seems close to this meaning:

> **b** : to have a usual or proper place or position : belong • these books *go* on the top shelf

Comment: thank you for your precise answer, I believe you solve my problem, thank you.